# Are $\mathbb{C}$ under addition and $\mathbb{C}$ under multiplication isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Is it true that $\mathbb{C}$ under addition and $\mathbb{C}^*$ under multiplication isomorphic?

I don't think we can use the argument that,  $\mathbb{C}$ have zero inside it, but,  $\mathbb{C}^*$ don't have. As, they are infinite sets anything can happen.

I have proved that, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^+,\cdot)$ are isomorphic using the map $x\mapsto e^x$. Can I use that? I can't see how that map will work here.

Can anyone please explain hoe to proceed? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The zero element is absorbing, i.e., $a\cdot 0 =0$ for all complex numbers $a$.

Comment: There are four numbers with $z\cdot z \cdot z \cdot z = 1$, the identity for multiplication, namely $1, -1, i, -i$; there's only one number with $w + w + w + w = 0$, the identity for addition, namely $w = 0$.

Comment: Maybe try to look for elements of order 2.

Comment: The exponential almost fits, doesn't it?

Comment: Note that $x \mapsto e^x$ is an isomorphism $(\Bbb R, +) \stackrel{\cong}{\to} (\Bbb R^+, \cdot)$.

Comment: @GEdgar and JohnHughes : - Ok got it, so they are not isomorphic. Please write it as an answer so that it can be marked as answered question.

Comment: @Travis Yeah, I have mentioned it in my question.

Comment: @KenOno The question asserts that $(\Bbb R, +)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R^*, \cdot)$, but $\Bbb R^*$ includes the negative reals, which are not in the image of $x \mapsto e^x$.

Comment: @Travis Ooh, my bad.

Comment: Ken, did you purposely choose a name of a known, currently active mathematician to use here?  Or do you maybe merely have the same name at that other "Ken Ono" at Emory University?

Comment: @GEdgar No, fortunately I have the same name :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any isomorphism between the non-zero complex numbers under multiplication and the complex numbers under addition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921883/is-there-any-isomorphism-between-the-non-zero-complex-numbers-under-multiplicati) and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814213/isomorphism-between-mathbbc-under-multiplication-with-mathbbc-under

Comment: Maybe add that to your profile:  "No, I am not the Ken Ono from Emory University."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because their torsion subgroups are different.

Indeed,
$(\mathbb C^*,\times)$ has an infinite number of torsion elements (the roots of unity), but $(\mathbb C,+)$ has just one torsion element (zero).

(A *torsion element* is an element of finite order.)

Therefore, no group homomorphism $(\mathbb C^*,\times) \to (\mathbb C,+)$ can be injective.

Comment: Can you specify which result we are using, when you have stated that `because their torsion subgroups are different` ?

Comment: @KenOno, if $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ is a group homomorphism, then $\phi$ sends torsion elements to torsion elements (not necessarily of the same order).

Answer (score 4):

You do not specify what sort of automprphism is wanted.  I will show $(\mathbb C,+)$ and $(\mathbb C^*,\cdot)$ are not isomorphic as groups.  The group $(\mathbb C,+)$ has no element of order $2$.  [$z+z=0$ implies $z=0$.] But the group $(\mathbb C^*,\cdot)$ does, namely $-1$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for the explanation.